# Is there a name for this acyclic quiver?

Tags: terminology, quiver

Sorry for the trivial question, but I don't know much about the subject and don't seem to be able to come up with much by Googling.  Is there an established name for quivers of the form

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdot @>>> \cdot @>>> \cdot \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\cdot @>>> \cdot @>>> \cdot \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\cdot @>>> \cdot @>>> \cdot
\end{CD}$$

(where there could be an arbitrary number of rows and columns)?  Actually I'm only interested in the case where it's a square, but surely that's not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quiver in your example could be called a *tensor product* of two copies of the quiver
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdot @>>> \cdot @>>> \cdot \\
\end{CD}$$
(which is a quiver of type $A_3$, linearly oriented).

This terminology appears, for instance, in section 3.3 of the paper *The periodicity conjecture for pairs of Dynkin diagrams*, by Bernhard Keller ([link to the arXiv version of the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.1531)).  It is quite likely that it has appeared before in the literature, although I could not find (and did not look too hard for) an earlier reference.

In the paper cited above, the tensor product of any two quivers $Q$ and $Q'$ is defined as follows:

- its vertices are pairs $(i,i')$, where $i$ is a vertex of $Q$ and $i'$ is a vertex of $Q'$;
- the number of arrows from $(i,i')$ to $(j,j')$ is given by these rules:

  - if $i\neq j$ and $i'\neq j'$, then it is equal to $0$;
  - if $i=j$, then it is equal to the number of arrows from $i'$ to $j'$;
  - if $i'=j'$, then it is equal to the number of arrows from $i$ to $j$.

Thus, to get a quiver as in your post with $m$ rows and $n$ columns, one should take the tensor product of a quiver of type $A_m$ with a quiver of type $A_n$, both linearly oriented.

Comment: Do you know a reference for names such as $A_n$, $B_2$, and so on. I mean, why Dynkin diagrams have those names?

Comment: @Sigur I don't know the history.  Perhaps this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#History) is a good place to start.